# Difference between 越える and 超える

Tags: homophonic-kanji, kanji-choice

What is the difference between `越える【こえる】` and `超える【こえる】`?

Comment: Related or duplicate: [The difference between 超える, 越える and 過ぎる](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/3477/9831)

Answer (score 4):

「越{こ}える」 means "to cross", "to go over", "to overreach", etc.

「超{こ}える」 means "to exceed", "to be above", "to surpass", etc.